# Client Socket in ISpy C# Plugin Connecting to Java Server Socket

Tags: c#, java, sockets, networking

I am trying to send only a simple string to my Java Application from an ISpy C# Plugin.

My Client code for the C# plugin is from this website... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx

My Java code is

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
                System.out.println("Server is up");

                Socket clientSocket = null;
                try 
                {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for incoming connections");
                    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    System.out.println("Accepted incoming connection");
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Accept failed: 8888");
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 8888");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
```

When I launch the ISpy application with the plugin loaded, the rest of the plugin performs as expected, but the Java Server Socket never receives a connection from the C# plugin. The Client code for the C# plugin is ran within a separate thread called by this code...

```
_networker = new Thread(() => SendTest()) { Name = "networker thread", IsBackground = false };
```

Where _networker is a handle for a Thread Object.

My question is, why isn't the C# client connecting to the Java server socket? The Java server socket was allowed when I was prompted by Windows. I am on Windows 8 64 bit.

If this seems as a bad way to solve my problem, I've already tried pipes, but that presents a bigger problem between communicating through the jvm and windows os.

If I could just read/write to a file between these programs I wouldn't be objected to that either. Whatever works, I'm not looking for speed or efficiency here.